# Error: View cannot be applied to Intent

Tags: java, android, service

I'm new to Android App Development and creating a simple service app. It has a button to start service and a button to stop service with their repective methods. Following is my code:

App3_main.java

```
package eg.app3;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class App3_main extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app3_main);
}

public void startservice(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
    startservice(intent); //this is where I'm getting the error mentioned in the title
}

public void stopservice(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
    stopservice(intent); //this is where I'm getting the error mentioned in the title
}

}
```

MyService.java

```
package eg.app3;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {
public MyService() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Service Started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Service Stopped",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Please guide me where I'm wrong.

Comment: What is the error you are getting @Junaid

Comment: have you add service in your AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: startservice (android.view.View) in App3_main cannot be applied to (android.content.Intent)

Comment: yes, I've already added service to manifest file

Comment: are you apply click listener in xml?

Comment: Where you call the startservice and stopservice

Comment: Yes. I'm using Android Studio. So, it goes like this in the layout xml file ... android:onClick="startservice"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
startservice(intent);
```

with:

```
startService(intent);
```

Then, replace:

```
stopservice(intent);
```

with:

```
stopService(intent);
```

Like most programming languages, Java is case-sensitive.